# Python property decorator usage in methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Kind of torn between this. This is not a question about how property works, rather it's usage. I do understand that property can be used to get, set, delete attributes. But my question is, is it OK to use it for actions or methods when I know that the method is never going to have any parameters ?
Reason for doing that - I feel it is more intuitive

Here is what I mean,

```py
Class Dancer(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    #this would be a typical use case
    @property
    def name(self):
       return self._name

    #is this ok ? 
    @property
    def dance(self):
       print("moves like jagger")
       return self

dancer = Dancer("levine")
print(dancer.name)
dancer.dance    #why not ?
```

I started doing this for a project of mine (only for cases where it made sense). But started receiving backlash for doing that ? What is wrong with this ? Any thoughts, suggestions ?

P.S. I know that such methods will never have parameters

Comment: It's suggested by [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to create readonly methods. Your function returns readonly attributes so I don't see difference. It's also used for this case: `def size(self): return len(self.data)` with `@property`

Comment: Yes, but size is also some property and not a true action, like dance :-). 
My question is can I also use it for actions and not just to return some attribute value

Comment: I wouldn't do it. If I saw `dancer.dance.name` I'd be wondering where/what the heck is the name attribute of a dance object? `dancer.dance().prance().sleep()` would be the expected way to see chained actions.

Comment: What do you precisely mean by "action"? It's not a programming term. Isn't `len(self.data)` an "action"? I'm confused.

Comment: Or you are saying you're doing some manipulation: `def dance(self): self.name += 'next_str'` then it violates the definition of "readonly" so it would be discouraged.

Comment: @knh190, action as in, it's really a method doing some processing (let's say). Even better example would like, say you have a browser object and you want to make browser.refresh a property and not a method call (i.e instead of browser.refresh())

Comment: No, I wouldn't be modifying anything with respect to current object or it's attributes

Comment: It's syntactically fine, but it's an abuse of what properties are for. `dance` should *get* some value, but you are only using it for the side effect of producing some output. Just make it a regular method.